# Make index use using calculative field T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

We do have one query which is running very frequently but as we are using function on both side of column, it's not doing index seek and this query turn out to be one of the most expensive query. Is there any way i can make this column calculative?

```
SELECT TOP 1 column1
FROM table1
WHERE replace(replace(replace(column2, char(10), ''), char(13), ''), ' ', '') =
      replace(replace(replace(@var1, char(10), ''), char(13), ''), ' ', '')
```

Comment: Make a persisted calculated column on the table and index it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on dfundako's comment, you can make an index on a persisted calculated column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    column1 INT,
    column2 VARCHAR(50),
    column3 AS REPLACE(replace(replace(column2, char(10), ''), char(13), ''), ' ', '') PERSISTED
)

CREATE INDEX index1 ON table1 (column3) INCLUDE (column1)

DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
SELECT column1 FROM dbo.table1 WHERE column3=replace(replace(replace(@var1, char(10), ''), char(13), ''), ' ', '')
```